# Block area and not allow mouse effect it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want that the maze will not let the user start from a random position after the sad smiley shows up, any advice?

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/59/

```
$(".way").bind('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#highlight_lose').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
    $(".arrow").html("Try again");

    $('.arrow').bind().addClass('gradient');
    $('.arrow').bind().html('Try again!').css('color', '#000');


    function move() {
        console.log("t");
        $(".arrow").animate({
            "margin-left": "-=10px"
        }, 300, function () {
            $(".arrow").animate({
                "margin-left": "+=10px"
            }, 300, function () {
                $(".arrow").removeAttr('style');
                move();

            });
        });
    }
    $(".arrow").removeAttr('style');
    $(".arrow").clearQueue().stop().finish();
    move();
})
```

Comment: Check if the first square is already checked, and if not, reject checking of the currently hovered square (if it's not the first one itself) ...?

Comment: @CBroe ok sounds right... can u show me how to 'reject' checking plz?

Comment: @CBroe noticed that after you get to the finish point it don't start/working do u have a solution for that ? http://jsfiddle.net/neogauravsvnit/uqcLn/60/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CBRoe's answer is right. I was playing with your jsfiddle and I updated it. Check if this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/neogauravsvnit/uqcLn/60/

I just modified the js part a bit

```
$(".wall").hover(function () {
    //$(this).css("background", '#000');
    if($("#wall_first").hasClass("wall-black") || $(this).attr("id") == "wall_first"){
        $(this).addClass("wall-black");
    }
    $('#highlight_lose').fadeOut(1000);
    $(".arrow").removeAttr('style');
    $(".arrow").clearQueue().stop().finish();
    $ (".arrow"). html ("START HERE!");
})


$(".way").bind('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#highlight_lose').fadeIn(1000);
    //$('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
    $(".wall").removeClass("wall-black");
    $(".arrow").html("Try again");

    $('.arrow').bind().addClass('gradient');
    $('.arrow').bind().html('Try again!').css('color', '#000');





    function move() {
        console.log("t");
        $(".arrow").animate({
            "margin-left": "-=10px"
        }, 300, function () {
            $(".arrow").animate({
                "margin-left": "+=10px"
            }, 300, function () {
                $(".arrow").removeAttr('style');
                move();

            });
        });
    }
    $(".arrow").removeAttr('style');
    $(".arrow").clearQueue().stop().finish();
    move();
})
```

I added an id element in the first class type wall.. And I defined the class wall-black so that you can effectively check if the first box has been hovered over..

Comment: this is beautiful solution for me works great!! thanks very very much for your time and answer...

Comment: noticed that after get to the finish point it don't start/working do u have a solution for that ?

Comment: woops.. Missed out the finish functions .. Here, updated it http://jsfiddle.net/neogauravsvnit/uqcLn/64/